# htaccess routing through index.php without allowing www

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I have a shared hosting account through GoDaddy, and the site I have on it uses .htaccess to route all requests through index.php. This works fine on its own.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

I then wanted to restrict it to using non-www urls, so I added the following before it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So altogether it is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

However, together these two do not work. The URL tries to redirect to /missing.html for URLs that should be routed. Separately these both are fine. Is there a way to get both things working together?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the first `L` tag If you want to make them work together.Because `L` means **if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]   //remove L from this line

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that works for the URL routing, but if I put "www." before a URL that should be routed, it takes me to /missing.html